# Organization on database with userId field in a microservice archecture

Tags: security, oauth, architecture, microservices, openid-connect

I have a question on micro-service architecture. example I have :

- An authorization and authentication server which provide JWT (Keycloak for exemple)
- 2 micro service which communicate between them through REST.
- 1 micro service is a user service which create a new user in my database on each new user from the Keycloak (may be tomorrow we have Google or Github, it's important to take this in mind). When I'm creating a user I store his subject from claim in a specific field.
- 1 micro service which store the creatorId, the updateById for blog post for exemple.

Is it better to store in my creatorId and updatedById the subject (Like this I don't need to ask to my user service to identify who is a creator) or to store the userId from my user service and everytime call from my post-service which is the user that made the request (So I made Everytime a rest request to get the user which send the request by passing the JWT token to the user service).

IMO, sending Everytime a rest request will increase the load on the user service but a subject id for a different user can be the same for Google, Github and Keycloak.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following, so that you can move to a different Authorization Server (Google / Github) in future without too much impact:

- User Service creates a row in its Users Table for each new user, with a database surrogate key as the main user id
- This user id is saved to your creatorId / updateById fields
- Meanwhile the OAuth Id / Sub claim is a column in the Users Table, but is not the main user identifier from business logic

The Posts Service can avoid calling the User Service on every single request if you cache claims in the Posts Service. Some resources of mine might give you some ideas that you can apply to your own solution:

- [User Management Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/)
- [Claims Caching Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/)
- [Claims Caching Code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts)

Comment: So I add a claim in the token ? With my user service ?